# Amazon SNS duplicates push notification

Tags: android, push-notification, amazon-sns

I'm sending SNS push through the AWS interface, and the following message sends me two pushes, of which only the second push is extensible and show me more than one line of text.

```
 {
    "GCM": "{ \"notification\": { \"body\": \"test message test test test message
     test test test message test test test message test test test message test   
     testtest message test test\" } }"
}
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**Solution:**
The app developers said that it was not prepared to receive pushes in format "notification", and that both duplicate messages as the  number of lines had to do with it. They will solve the problem of lines by adjusting the app.

Comment: So what did the developers change?

Comment: They ajusted the app to read correctly the type of sns push that was received. There are two types: notifications and data. In our case, it was incorrect. The app was Reading data, but sns message type was notification.For more details:  https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options